# Some objections

Tags: discussion, comment, deletion

I'd like to object to the deletion of the comments on my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158773/how-do-people-who-study-really-abstract-mathematics-imagine-or-understand-the/1161262#1161262).

If memory serves, Bill Dubuque commented there that he was concerned about over-eager deletion of material on the website, and those comments have now been deleted.

I object to this deletion on the grounds that it interferes with our right to hear other people's viewpoint on the direction the site should be heading; and furthermore, since I don't think meta provides a good place to discuss such things, this is a doubly serious issue. I therefore consider this a misuse of power and would like to register my disapproval here.

I also do not approve of the overly-rigid rules governing where things can be posted and what their content can be (both on the meta and on the main site), as it interferes with freedom of speech to unacceptable level.

Comment: I was the diamond moderator deleting all those comments. That was in response to flags from regular users. The comments were flagged as obsolete. Judging from the tone of the comments they were from an era when Bill Dubuque was fighting tooth and nail against deletions of questions. Anyway, any discussion about "the direction of the site" and "deletions of low quality questions" **should take place in meta**, and is **off-topic in main.** Therefore I see no reason to change the decision to delete those comments.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I appreciate that you meant well, but there's a variety of reasons why meta isn't always suitable for these sorts of chats. And being able to talk unimpeded with other users of the site about the politics of the site is REEEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAAAALLLLLLLLLLYYYYYYYYYYYYY important.

Comment: @goblin Having an unimpeded conversation with another user is always possible by sharing external contact information. But comments and posts here need to conform to the general quality standards, and meta specials are well off-topic on main.

Comment: and there's also chat, @goblin, which is far more flexible a place to converse in an unimpeded manner than your choice of doing so on main.  You haven't offered any support as to what the importance of  talking in an unimpeded manner on main, is, nor why that "important opportunity" cannot be met in chat, or on meta, or, in an exchange of contact info.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out: the comments were deleted **almost two years ago.** (July 2016)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen note that BD had self-deleted two of their three comments. When you came there the conversation was not even complete.

Comment: Indeed, I can only take "credit" for 3 out of 6 deletions. BD self-deleted two and Goblin one. I have no idea who was flagging.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Turns out it was me! :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Should I create a separate "new" meta post proposing a *Statute of Limitations* prohibiting a disgruntled user from running to meta to complain and lambast actions taken a full year, or two, prior to the posting of the plaintiff?

Comment: @Goblin, why are you objecting to the deletion of your first comment?  It was you who deleted it.

Answer (score 6):

As it so happens, I was involved in this. Initially I did not even recall this.

First, the comments *and the deletion* happened almost **two years ago**  (mid July 2016, see below for details).

Second, before any external intervention the conversation was rather hard to follow *by self-deletions* of your interlocutor.

Now, so that everybody can see what was lost, without further ado let me present all the deleted  comments there with the info who deleted them and when.

> - Why was this downvoted? I see nothing controversial in what I've written. – goblin Feb 23 '15 at 6:48 deleted by goblin Feb 25 '15 at 0:43
> - Believe it or not, there are now 4 delete votes on the question, so we will need to keep track of it lest the deletionists once again destroy helpful content. – Number Jul 17 '16 at 14:40 deleted by Number Jul 17 '16 at 15:05
> - @BillDubuque, thanks for the warning. Anything we can do about it? – goblin Jul 17 '16 at 14:41 deleted by Jyrki Lahtonen♦ Jul 18 '16 at 5:34
> - We can vote to undelete if it becomes deleted. Unfortunately SE provides no notification or review of deletions, so one needs to actively monitor the 10K Tools on deletions to track these things. The deletionists appear to be highly organized, but there appears to be zero organization to reverse such destruction. Maybe there should be a mailing list (it would need to be private since they would surely monitor it and it would lead to wars), – Number Jul 17 '16 at 14:50 deleted by Number Jul 17 '16 at 15:05
> - @BillDubuque, okay. Just let me know if it gets deleted, e.g. on another answer, and you'll have my undelete vote. Fundamentally, the problem is the lack of proper voting system ("for" and "against" the deletion.) – goblin Jul 17 '16 at 14:53 deleted by Jyrki Lahtonen♦ Jul 18 '16 at 5:34
> - Agreed. I usually monitor the 10K tools a few times a week to keep up on these matters (my cellphone reminds me with colorful quote from Abhyankar: [Eliminate the eliminators!](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2000-37-02/S0273-0979-99-00858-7/S0273-0979-99-00858-7.pdf)) The more folks we can coax into doing so the more we can reverse the destruction. – Number Jul 17 '16 at 15:05 deleted by Jyrki Lahtonen♦ Jul 18 '16 at 5:35

Some commentary. We can forget about the first I think as it was gone long before all this. Then a conversation was started about the fate of that question. I see nothing terribly wrong with this, but it is not really something that needs to be preserved for  posterity. Incidentally, as said above, your interlocutor apparently shares this judgment as they self-deleted their comments once they were read.

In particular, it then looked like this:

> - @BillDubuque, thanks for the warning. Anything we can do about it? – goblin
> - @BillDubuque, okay. Just let me know if it gets deleted, e.g. on another answer, and you'll have my undelete vote. Fundamentally, the problem is the lack of proper voting system ("for" and "against" the deletion.) – goblin
> - Agreed. I usually monitor the 10K tools a few times a week to keep up on these matters (my cellphone reminds me with colorful quote from Abhyankar: [Eliminate the eliminators!](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2000-37-02/S0273-0979-99-00858-7/S0273-0979-99-00858-7.pdf)) The more folks we can coax into doing so the more we can reverse the destruction. – Number

The first two reply to something that is not visible anymore. Little point in keeping those around I think. And, the last one is even a digression beyond the question at hand.  Thus, I had flagged as "obsolete" (the first two) and "too chatty" (the last). Chances are that had I not flagged the last, it would have been self-deleted, too.

Comment: Wow; quite revealing, and in particular, makes the deletions of such comments (self deletions or otherwise) entirely transparent and understandable!  Thanks for this.